# Нужно ли обособление уточнения?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, уточнения

Обязательно ли обособлять запятыми уточнение?
Или здесь может иметься в виду не оно?

Предложение:

> Хозяин Джона Эрриксона, Эдуард Петрович, тут же проявил недовольство.

А так?

> Хозяин Джона Эрриксона Эдуард Петрович тут же проявил недовольство.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможны два варианта:

(1) **Хозяин Джона Эрриксона Эдуард Петрович тут же проявил недовольство.**

Определительное значение.  В данном случае недовольство проявляет Эдуард Петрович, который является хозяином Джона Эрриксона.

(2) **Хозяин Джона Эрриксона, Эдуард Петрович, тут же проявил недовольство.**

Уточняющее значение. В данном случае недовольство проявляет хозяин Джона Эрриксона (по имени Эдуард Петрович).

Answer (score 1):

Здесь можно и без обособления - в зависимости от того, на чем делает акцент автор. Если важно Сказать что это был именно Эдуард Петрович, а то что он хозяин - второстепенно и именно это может рассматриваться как некое уточнение, то обособления не требуется.

Но вообще-то куда более реальным выглядит тот вариант, что именно "Эдуард Петрович" здесь приложение, а смысловой акцент падает на то, что он чей-то там хозяин. Поэтому вне какого-то особого контекста обособление вполне нормально.

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае нет необходимости в обособлении, поскольку склоняемость первого имени не приводит к недоразумениям (ср. "Начальник Петрова Сидоров поступил так-то"). Но оно понадобилось бы при проблемах с распознаванием границ имени:

> Хозяйка (горничной) Элисон Эрриксон, Бриджит Нильсен, тут же проявила
>   недовольство.

Comment: Вот это важное дополнение.